# weblogic api and curl

Tags: api, curl, weblogic

I'm just wondering if there's a restful api or curl commands for 12c versions below to managed the servers in weblogic like doing stop, start of the specific server.

I have tried the below api link for version 12.1.3.0.0 (12c) and managed to get what i wanted.

```
https://[Host]:[Port]/management/wls/latest/servers/id/[Servername]/shutdown?force=true
```

However, in the previous versions like 10.3.6.0. (11g) it doesn't seems to work even if use some curl commands. my reason for this is i just want to automate some actions in weblogic.

can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST Management API has been introduced in WebLogic Server 12c. This feature does not exist in previous version.
WLST is the recommanded way to automate your actions. Note that a simple shell script is enough to start/stop a server instance.

Comment: I think that would be sufficient too, i've been doing wlst for now. thanks a lot